# Font Color Set Incorrectly when using UITableView and Conditional

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, tableview

I have a UITableView set up with a Core Data fetched results controller and custom cells created using a storyboard. Everything is working fine until I try conditionally setting the font color of a UILabel for some cells.

By default in the storyboard, each cell shows a "departure time" with a grey font. But, if the cell represents the user's current location, the font should be blue. So I set up a conditional in configureCell (near the bottom of this snippet):

```
-(void) configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([cell isMemberOfClass:[SectionDividerCell class]])  {
        [self configureSectionDividerCell:(SectionDividerCell *)cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else if ([cell isMemberOfClass:[VisitCell class]])  {
        [self configureVisitCell:(VisitCell *)cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

-(void) configureVisitCell:(VisitCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    //Regular visit cell

    Visit *visit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Set text content
    cell.titlePlace.text = visit.place_name;
    cell.arriveText.text = [visit getArrivalTimeDisplay:@"hh:mm a"];
    cell.leaveText.text = [visit getDepartureTimeDisplay:@"hh:mm a"];
    cell.durationText.text = visit.durationDisplay;

    //Set fonts
    [cell.durationText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-BoldCondensed" size:20.0]];
    [cell.arriveText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:12.0]];
    [cell.titlePlace setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-BoldCondensed" size:17.0]];

    //If current location, make text blue
    if (!visit.departure_time)    {
        [cell.leaveText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:12.0]];
        [cell.leaveText setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }
    else    {
        [cell.leaveText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:12.0]];

    }

    //Get Image for cell
    if (!cell.imgThumb.image)   {

        NSString *imageURL = [[docDir stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:visit.place.imageName];
        [cell.imgThumb setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageURL]];
    }

}
```

With the above code, the "Current Location" cell's UILabel is correctly colored blue, but some other cells are also colored blue (seems to be random - happens to about 10% of the cells.

If I add this code within the else statement to set the color back to the default for cells that are not the current location, it fixes the problem:
            [cell.leaveText setTextColor:[UIColor greyColor]];

But what I don't understand is, why are some cells incorrectly having their font color set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are some cells incorrectly having their font color set?

It's not incorrect.

> If I add this code within the else statement to set the color back to the default for cells that are not the current location, it fixes the problem: `[cell.leaveText setTextColor:[UIColor greyColor]];`

Yes, exactly. That's because UITableView, for the sake of reducing memory footprint, re-uses table view cells. And when a cell is reused, UITableView doesn't reset its properties, so **You** have to reset them to defaults. You can see this pattern in some code of mine, too, for example, [this file browser UITableView](https://github.com/H2CO3/Fridge/blob/master/FileBrowserViewController.m) shows symbolic links using light blue, but normal files in the default black color. Here you can also see the `else` branch of the conditional statement.

```
// test for symlink
if (readlink([childPath UTF8String], NULL, 0) != -1) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1f green:0.3f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
} else {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```